# How to make toggle button responsive?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I don't know how to make the bootstrap style responsive with my input.

Because every time I've tried to implement it, it's rendering a basic ugly checkbox. And I loose my style.

I have a field `:secret(boolean)`, and I would like to make a toggle button with that.

That's my code :

```css
/*** TOGGLE DEFAULT ***/

.TriSea-technologies-Switch>input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.TriSea-technologies-Switch>label {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
}

.TriSea-technologies-Switch>label::before {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 8px;
  content: '';
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  width: 40px;
}

.TriSea-technologies-Switch>label::after {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  content: '';
  height: 24px;
  left: -4px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 24px;
}

.TriSea-technologies-Switch>input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background: inherit;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.TriSea-technologies-Switch>input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  background: inherit;
  left: 20px;
}


/*** TOGGLE DEFAULT ***/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-inputs">
  <h4>
    Nom du groupe :
  </h4>
  <%= f.input :name, label: false %>
    <br>
    <h4 style="width: 330px; text-align:center; margin-left:30px;">
      <div class="pull-left">
        Groupe secret
      </div>
      <div class="TriSea-technologies-Switch pull-right" style="margin-right:20px;">
        <input id="TriSeaSuccess" name="TriSea1" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="TriSeaSuccess" class="label-success"></label>
      </div>
    </h4>
    <%= f.hidden_field :admin, :value => current_user.id  %>
</div>
```

Should I use a gem for that? Or I can make it directly with a secret do or a JavaScript function?